# How to remove Blanks coming in between an IQML program on attentional blink task

Tags: image, debugging, qml

I am trying to run an IQML program related to an attentinal blink task on Inquisit Lab but I'm getting blanks in between my trial runs of images, How do I remove this blank and is this due to the input images or a code error?

The program does not gives any error on debugging, I tried to reduce the input image size but still getting the blanks in between the trial, but this reduces when I run it in the "Monkey Run" option of the Inquisit software

```
<block test>
/ onblockbegin = [
    values.phase = "test";
    values.blockCounter += 1;
    values.trialCounter_perblock = 0;
]
/ trials = [1= testBlockIntro; 2 = fixation]//runs as many trialsequences as calculated to run a fully balanced block
/ branch = [
    if (values.blockCounter < parameters.numberTestBlocks){
        return block.test;
    }
]
</block>



<block finish>
/ trials = [1 = finish]
</block>
```